# NSMutableDictionary Not Threadsafe: So?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I've had a **very** rarely occurring bug where a key in an `NSMutableDictionary` instance ends up pointing to the wrong object (another object in the same dictionary).

**Could "key confusion" be the result of a race condition?**

Here's the code (I've put in new thread safety since):

```
- (NSNumber*) makeHashFromResizedImage:(UIImage*)original newSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    int retVal = original.hash + newSize.width * 2 + newSize.height * 4;
    return [NSNumber numberWithInteger:retVal];
}

- (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image newSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    NSNumber *key = [self makeHashFromResizedImage:image newSize:newSize];

    if ([self.resizedImages objectForKey:key]) {
        return [self.resizedImages objectForKey:key];
    }

    UIImage *newImage = {{image-resizing-code-here}};

    [self.resizedImages setObject:newImage forKey:key];

    return newImage;
}
```

**Note**: `{{image-resizing-code-here}}` was removed for brevity. I'm beginning to suspect my `makeHashFromResizedImage` as it probably doesn't work as expected. Going to Unit Test it now.

Comment: Please show your code. (and yes, [NSDictionary isn't thread-safe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986736/nsmutabledictionary-thread-safety).)

Comment: @KennyTM I was going to say my code is not relevant, but surely it is relevant and I'm probably looking at the wrong thing. My `makeHashFromResizedImage` looks like it might be having float-and-int problems, too, for instance. Code is posted.

Comment: If you are worried about making NSDictionary thread safe, look at this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763028/how-can-i-make-every-message-an-object-receives-thread-safe)

Comment: Thanks @RichardJ.RossIII I'm not worried, and in fact I don't tink it's a problem in this context. I'm beginning to think that my problem is much simpler: I think I've screwed up `makeHashFromResizedImage`. Checking that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
if ([self.resizedImages objectForKey:key]) {
    return [self.resizedImages objectForKey:key];
}
```

If another thread called `setObject:forKey:` with that `key` the result of the 2nd line will be different from the first line. Why not just store it in a variable? At least the thing you check and the thing you return will be the same.

```
UIImage* image = [[[[self.resizedImages objectForKey:key] retain] autorelease];
if (image) {
    return image;
}
```

(The `retain` + `autorelease` is just to retain `image` won't be `-dealloc`-ed when this thread is running.)

If you have to ensure that the `key` corresponding to that `image` will not be overwritten before the function returns, you'll need to use a lock, as others answered.

---

**Edit:** Perhaps you should use an NSMutableSet of the UIImage instead. Especially, don't use a hash value as a key! A hash value does not need to be different when the two objects are not the same. Create a new class X which contains a CGSize and UIImage property, and use a NSMutableSet of X, if the same UIImage can be added multiple times.

Comment: Thanks! First off, this is all under ARC, just to simplify. Secondly, I don't mind if somebody else subs the object for my key, because it SHOULD be pointing to the same image, resized the same way. Now I'm beginning to suspect my hash function, which looks quite wrong.

Comment: @Yar: If it's in ARC then just leave off the `retain` and `autorelease` because a __strong variable should have done that for you.

Comment: Thanks @KennyTM, I will try a custom key class that takes a `CGSize` and a `UIImage`, carefully overriding `isEqual:`

Answer (score 2):

As Rob said;  you need to provide exclusion yourself.

Yes, "key confusion" *could* be a result of a race condition, but it is exceedingly unlikely.  More likely that you would end up with intermittent crashes.   But, sure, misplaced values could happen because of corruption and undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks. I'm probably not looking at the right problem. I updated the question with some code.

Answer (score -1):

`NSMutableDictionary` is not thread safe. It is up to you to provide locking.

Comment: Are you answering the title to the question, or the question?