# run time catch method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make every message an object receives thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763028/how-can-i-make-every-message-an-object-receives-thread-safe)

I need to catch action of another class when doing some event

for example when doing some event, SomeClass call someMethod, I need catch someMethod

```
@implementation MyClass

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Class newClass = objc_getClass("SomeClass");

}
@end
```

Comment: Check this http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html if it helps.

Comment: It may not look like a dupe,  but read it fully to understand.